# Reading in hourly data with pd.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading in a csv file with pd.read_csv()

The data contains a financial OHLC time series, it's hourly data.
The date and the hour are values seperated with a , .

Now I have two series, one for date and one for hour.
Is there a way to use the two values in one series so I can convert the whole thing to a datetime object.

The read method should skip the first comma and use the two first (date and hour) values to store in a series that I will use as index.

`df = pd.read_csv (csvpath, names=['Date', 'Hour', 'Open_Price','High_Price','Low_Price','Close_Price'], usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`

I tried converting the hour data to a datetime object but now it's assigning dates to it that don't match the actual data.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an issue with the format of the dates being parsed from your CSV.

`to_datetime` accepts a `format` parameter, which is a string you should create based on the format of the dates you are reading from the CSV.  Note that when you leave this parameter off, `to_datetime` will make a best effort to guess the format of the dates you're parsing.  Here's a reference for how you can create the format string: http://strftime.org/

As a simple example: if your dates look like `02-12-19`, you could use: `pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%m-%d-%y')`

Comment: Solved it by creating a new csv and then reading it in with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a new csv and then reading it in with pandas.

```
def csv_edit(csv_in, csv_out):
# Reads in first two columns (Dates and hours)
Date, Hour = np.loadtxt (csv_in, dtype = 'str', delimiter = ',', unpack = True, usecols=[0,1])
# Reads in ohlc data
df = pd.read_csv(csv_in, delimiter = ',', names=['Open_Price','High_Price','Low_Price','Close_Price'], usecols = [2,3,4,5])
# Combines dates and hours to one series
df['Date'] = [x + '.' + y for x, y in zip(Date, Hour)]
# Sets index to Date
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
# Writes to new csv
df.to_csv(csv_out)
```